# screen shifted when lines count changed

Tags: android, android-layout

I am displaying text description in two lines using `TextView`. I am using `android:maxLines="2"`, `android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"` & `android:ellipsize="end"` major attributes in `xml` file. I am fetching text by web service. So if I received one line text then `TextView` in `layout` display position shifted above when I switch from one `viewpager` to another. Also if I add `android:minLines="2"` then surprisingly layout display position shifted little down when I switch from one viewpager to another. I tried a lot of experiments to solve this issue, but not succeeded. Can anybody please help me to solve same issue.